# Confirm closing Colorbox

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I want to display simple confirmation popup box if a user tries to close colorbox. I tried this code:

```
onCleanup:function(){ confirm('Are you sure'); }
```

It displays confirmation box but colorbox is closed even if I click "Cancel"!

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if colorbox allows to cancel the closing once you have started it ..

If it did, though, you would need to change your code to

```
onCleanup:function(){ return confirm('Are you sure'); }
```

Comment: could always modify ColorBox to add a callback onBeforeClose which takes into account return values from the callback/callbacks

Comment: @Jonathan, indeed. And from a look at the source it is pretty straight forward how to do it ..

Answer (score 9):

There already is a [nice example in the FAQ of colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq#faq-close)

You have to redefine colorbox' close method:

```
var originalClose = $.colorbox.close;
$.colorbox.close = function(){
  if (confirm('Do you want to close this window?')) {
    originalClose();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I've done something similar with FancyBox. I think your best bet is to bind an event handler to the close button when the ColorBox is displayed:

```
onComplete:function(){
  $("#cboxClose").click(function(e) {
    // stop any other script from firing
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    if (confirm('Are you sure')) {
      $.colorbox.close();
      // ensure that the binding is removed when closed
      $("#cboxClose").unbind();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@Ken, your example worked perfectly for me...almost.  The only modification that I had to make was to unbind before setting the click function because for some reason, it would ignore my if statement and still close on first load.  Below is what I have put into use for a confirmation on closing a colorbox

```
$(".Add").colorbox({
    onComplete:function(e){
       $("#modalForm").ajaxForm(modalOptions);
       $("#cboxClose").unbind(); 
       $("#cboxClose").click(function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
          if(confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel your changes?')){
             $.colorbox.close();
             $("#cboxClose").unbind();                               
          }                           
       }); 
    }
   });
```

Comment: This works great!  Is there a way to only show the message IF something was changed on the page opened in colorbox?

Comment: @Dennis, I would attach a onChange handler  on all inputs for that form using jQuery.  If that function is called, set a variable (eg `var hasChanged = false; //for default init value`) to true - `$("#colorboxFormId:input").on("change", function(){hasChanged = true;})`.  Then your `if(confirm...)` would become `if(hasChanged && confirm(....)`.  Apologize for the typos in this code - its off the top of my head as the method I would pursue.

Comment: @Dennis - Also note that if your colorbox content is being loaded via AJAX, then you would need to attach this handler either after the content is loaded or reference a parent element on the screen that exists when your page loads.  Else, the handler will never attach to the form as it doesn't exist when the page first loads.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  We are using iframe, that was throwing a monkey wrench in to this.